# How to upload the JSF Project into web

Tags: jsf

How do I upload the `JavaServerFace` Project, that I created in *eclipse*, to the internet?

It's a dynamic web page project; Is there a special program or is it uploaded just as a normal website would be? Do I have to put the files in a jar file, war file?

Everything works fine when I launch it from *eclipse* with *tomcat*. Do I need to somehow put tomcat in the web server? (I'm just guessing here). I have tried uploading it just as I would a normal website, but turns out I can't see the content of my main login page.

When I tried viewing it with *InternetExplorer*, after uploading the project using `WS_FTP`, IE prompted my to download the file? When I go to the view page source, under view, I see the actual syntax, but the form doesn't show up in the browser window. The file extension is .xhtml, because *eclipse* wouldn't show me anything when I set the file extension to .html (When I tried to run with the server).

I also couldn't use .jsp because *eclipse* gave me a:

> NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config error

(Is `.xhtml` mandatory?). I am using *Tomcat 7*, *eclipse*, the newest version of *eclipse* that I downloaded a month ago, and *JSF2.0* (*Mojarra 2.0*).

I first tried downloading every individual file from every folder, the ones that I could that is. When that didn't work I downloaded the individual folders, after that the whole `JSFProject` folder, needless to say it failed every time.

I hope I have provided enough information. I'm not worried about how to make java server faces work, I know I can figure it out, but how do I upload it? I have searched this for days (literally- I'm a college student, so research is what I'm accustomed to, but I couldn't find any leads regarding this subject at all. This may be basic, but I just need a push in the right direction.)

Comment: Can you please provide your web.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need to install tomcat on the web server! follow the steps:

1. Download tomcat as a windows service [Tomcat 7 download](http://apache.spd.co.il//tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.4-beta/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.4.exe) and double click to run it and install it.
2. In Eclipse, stand on your project and right click: export->war and choose your location (desktop).
3. copy the are to %tomcat_home% (on your web server) -> webapp.
4. open your computer's services console (if you have windows7 just type it in the search command. Otherwise it should be under accessories)
5. look for apache tomcat and restart the server.
6. point to the same URL that you used in your pc.

Comment: Sorry to be a nuisance, i have a few questions regarding your response, for which i am extremely thankful as well.

Comment: Ok. When you say copy to tomcat_home, i assume it's inside the webapps folder created when tomcat7 was installed.Correct?

Comment: awww.sorry every time i press enter, instead of new line it just posts.aagggg. But just for clarity what do you mean web server. When i think of we server i think of internet browser(firefox, etc.). If so, ho do i put it there?  And, when i try to start the apche tomcat server, running the tomcat7w.exe file found under bin, it doesnt start. It begins but 1/3 of the way in it just dissapears. Any ideas why? As far as pointing to the url, i assume i will provide tomcat with it after it starts, which it hasnt for me, if i'm wrong please correct me as to when i tell tomcat of the url. Thank you

Comment: Also i take it the computer service console is the cmd.exe command or the run(a program in my vista o/s).

Comment: i cant put the web.xml, this page eliminates the tags and it looks like a run on sentence with no xml tags- this is my first time posting anyting really, so i dont know how to.

Comment: also the JSFProject.war file, is it extracted or what, because when i try to open it with tomcat it doesnt show it just prompts me to open a file. Unlike running the individual files which show up normally(remember i dont have problem with running it on my localhost, what i want is to run to project online on a website.)

Comment: 1. correct 2. web server - I mean your hosting company of the site, or your own server that works on the internet. in order to run tomcat you have to install it. after the installation you have to restart the service as i mentions in #4. 3. web.xml - you can edit the code by clicking on the code symbol in the line above the place where you enter the question (you have to mark it and than click on code). 4. war is like a zip file for web application. when you start tomcat it should unwar it.

Answer (score -1):

you can just go get a tomcat-server and put it there

reading your question and some answers, i think youre better off with that and save a lot of time.

http://www.java-hoster.com/en/index.php id go there, they seem to have just what u need